# UICollectionViewLayout subclass

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I've created a UICollectionView in a storyboard and changed it's type to custom and selected my UICollectionViewLayout subclass as its class.

Within the UICollectionViewLayout subclass is the following code.  But I don't see anything at all in the collectionview when I run the app.  What am I missing please?

```
@implementation CollectionViewLayout

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        // Do something
        NSLog(@"init with coder");

        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        self = [super init];

        self.imageArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(int i = 0; i <32; i++)
        {
            NSString *imageToLoad = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.JPG", i];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageToLoad];
            [self.imageArray addObject:image];
        }

        longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressGestureRecognized:)];
        longPress.delegate = self;
        [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
        [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

        self.collectionView.delegate = self;
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return [self.imageArray count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{

    NSLog(@"cell for item");

    Cell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCellID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[cell viewWithTag:999] removeFromSuperview];
    self.isDeleteActive = NO;
    cell.image.image = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

These methods are from 'UICollectionViewDataSource' that should not be implemented in the custom layout class.